# trace of inverse operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inverse

Let $H$ be an RPK-Hilbert space and $K:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be the reproducing Kernel s.t. $K$ is bounded by $1$. For some Probability Space $(X, \nu)$
It is assumed that all $f \in H$ are measurable and
bounded in supremum norm s.t. $\|f\|_\infty ≤ 1$. Therefore, $H$ is
a subset of $L^2(X , ν)$ , with $S : H \rightarrow L^2(X , ν)$ being the inclusion operator, satisfying $\|S\|\leq 1$.

Consider the compact linear Operator $L=S^*S$ which is given by
$$Lf=\int_{X}\left\langle f, K(.,x)\right\rangle_{H} K(.,x) \nu(d x)$$

It can be show that $\|L\|\leq1$.

Now the following inequality was used:

$\text{Trace}[(L+\lambda)^{-1}L]\leq1$,

for $\lambda\in(0,1]$.
The Trace is defined as
$\text{Trace}[L]=\sum_{i\in I}<L\,e_i,e_i>$, for some ONB $\{e_i\}$
Does someone has an idea why this should hold?
Also im not sure if $\lambda$ should be read as $\lambda I$ where $I$ is the idendity Operator or if $\lambda$ is just a constant?

Comment: Can you recall what is trace in this situation?

Comment: There must be other constraints here (are you finite dimensional?). For instance, take $L=I$ and then the operator in the trace is not trace class and so the inequality does not make sense. Or even in finite dimensions if you take $L = I$ and $\lambda = 1$ then the trace evaluates to $d/2$ where $d$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space which is $> 1$ for all $d > 2$.

Comment: In addition to what Rammus said, the operator $L+\lambda$ is not necessarily invertible for your range of $\lambda$. So you'll have to provide more context and/or disclose the paper you found.

Comment: Thank you very much. Im sorry for my mistake. I think the assumptions are complete know.

Comment: Bounded in supremum norm does not mean $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$, and indeed this inequality can only hold if $H=\{0\}$. Moreover, if $\mathrm{Tr}((L+\lambda)^{-1}L)\leq 1$ would hold for all $\lambda\in(0,1]$, we could take the limit $\lambda\searrow 0$ and get $\mathrm{Tr}(I)\leq 1$. But of course this is only true if $\operatorname{dim}H\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why should the function Tr$(...)^{-1}$ be continuous in $\lambda$ at zero?

Comment: maybe i should mention that the left hand side of the inequality is also called the effective dimension

Comment: The convergence $(L+\lambda)^{-1}L\to I$ as $\lambda\searrow 0$ is monotone, i.e., $\langle (L+\lambda)^{-1}L e_i,e_i\rangle\nearrow 1$. Thus convergence convergence of the trace follows from the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you tell me what you mean by monoton sequence of operators exactly? And is there maybe an other definition for the trace of an operator?